# Django view: good programming practice question

Tags: django

suppose that you have a webpage that uses the post and get method, and you wrote the following view to generate it:

```
def homepage(request):
if 'login' in request.POST:
# ......... code goes here, and you return an appropriate response 

if 'register' in request.POST:
# ......... code goes here, and you return an appropriate response  

# When no Post request, just render the page
return render_to_response('homepage.html')
```

**Question:**

Is it considered good programming practice to split the above view into three views: one for login, one for register and one that would render the page? Or is it OK to keep it as it is.

**EDIT**

in the case listed above, I am not checking if the server received a "GET". But the idea is still the same :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a better idea would be to have each of the two forms submit to a different URL. Then you can define views for, e.g., `/login`, `/register`, and `/` (the default homepage handler). Your views for `/login` and `/register` can use `if request.method == 'POST'`, and then redirect to the homepage if they are called with a GET request.

Comment: A _much_ better idea. This separates the logic which is always a good thing.

Comment: Yes I was considering doing something like this, as having everything in one view is making the code look "cumbersome" and "clumsy". Thank you for the response :)